# Inserting rsPhone value from each loop to strSQL MS ACCESS

Tags: ms-access, vba, recordset

I have this piece of code:

```
Private Sub cmdAdd_Click()

Dim dbs As DAO.Database
Dim rsPhone As DAO.Recordset

        If IsNull(Me.listPrzyczyna) Or Me.listPrzyczyna = "" Then
            MsgBox "Wybierz przyczynę awarii!", vbOKOnly, "Wymagane dane"
            Me.listPrzyczyna.SetFocus

        Else

    Set dbs = CurrentDb
    Set rsPhone = dbs.OpenRecordset("dbZmiana")
    Do While Not rsPhone.EOF

    Dim strSQL As String
    Dim strSQLSMSSend As String

        strSQL = "INSERT INTO dbAwarieOtwarte (nrMaszyny, nazwaMaszyny, Zglaszajacy, dataZgloszenia, dataZakonczenia, godzinaZgloszenia, Przyczyna, Obszar, Telefon, Komentarz) VALUES ('" & Me!txtNrMaszyny & "', '" & Me!txtNazwa & "', '" & Me!txtZglaszajacy & "', '" & Me!txtData & "', '" & Me!txtData & "', '" & Me!txtGodzina & "', '" & Me!listPrzyczyna & "," & Me!txtNazwa & "," & Me!txtNrMaszyny & "," & Me!txtObszar & "', '" & Me!txtObszar & "', '" & Me!txtTel & "', '" & Me!txtKomentarz & "');"
        strSQLSMSSend = "INSERT INTO dbSMSSend (Przyczyna, Telefon) VALUES ('" & Me!SMSSendRequest & "', '" & txtTel & "');"
        DoCmd.SetWarnings False
        DoCmd.RunSQL strSQL
        DoCmd.RunSQL strSQLSMSSend
        DoCmd.SetWarnings True

    rsPhone.MoveNext
    Loop
    rsPhone.Close
    Set rsPhone = Nothing
    dbs.Close
    Set dbs = Nothing

        DoCmd.Close
'        DoCmd.OpenReport "repAwariaOtwarta", acViewPreview, , "ID=" & DMax("ID", "dbAwarieOtwarte")
        End If

End Sub
```

It's loop for each phone number in dbZmiana, so I have separated strSQL insert for each number provided.

Everything is smooth, but i bumped to an issue. In each loop i want to insert "looped" phone number as string into strSQLSMSSend.
This number should go into Telefon and i dont know how to refer to that rs value in each loop.

For now there is a '" & txtTel & "' value, how do i Insert rs value instead of it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about:

```
strSQLSMSSend = "INSERT INTO dbSMSSend (Przyczyna, Telefon) VALUES ('" & Me!SMSSendRequest & "', '" & rsPhone!txtTel.Value & "');"
```

Comment: You missunderstood me, i dont need txtTel field, i just need rsPhone value. If I'll insert there '" & rsPhone & "' I get error: Method 'Item' of object 'Forms' failed and debug redirects me to different form to vba code: Forms!formAwarieObszar1.Requery so i assume im taking that rs value somehow wrong.

Comment: rsPhone is the recordset. You must use a field like rsPhone!Somefield

Comment: ok so now there is a part where I feel confused. Whole script suposed to loop that strSQL's and for every of them add different phone number. Loop is repeated by the number of phone numbers in specified table. Everything is ok but it seems i will have hard time to grab these phone number values. I feel dump, dunno how to grab that.

Comment: If the value to insert is not from a field of rsPhone, I'm not sure what you try to do - and you must retrieve the value in some other way.

Comment: Oh ok, i was thinking about rsPhone more like an array, which is not. Simply i needed rsPhone!Phone.Value to kinda "iterate" through numbers in "Phone" collumn. Thank You, that quite helped a lot! I got confused, because txtTel was a combobox which i typed there just for tests :)

Comment: Oh, I see. That explains.